# ireport 5.5.1 print when expression using two variables with OR expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to print when one of two variables is true, but I cannot figure out the syntax that ireport is looking for in the "Print When Expression" field. This is the expression I'm trying to use:

```
(!$F{pay_type}.equals("ACA Fee"))||($V{bill_amt}.floatValue() != 0.00)
```

Each part works independently but when I combine them with the ||, it breaks down.

I have also tried: `((!$F{pay_type}.equals("ACA Fee"))||($V{bill_amt}.floatValue() != 0.00)) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE`

Comment: Your expression seems ok (Not considering that you should never check if float is zero, but that's another story), which error do you get? and which version of jasper reports are you using?

Comment: @AaronMyerson `I need to print when one of two variables is true` - BTW, *$F{pay_type}* is not a variable, it is a field